# Angular HTTP request for an outside api 401 error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, http-headers

I'm trying to access the below api with my code

```
curl --request GET \
  --url https://api.collectapi.com/corona/countriesData \
  --header 'authorization: apikey your_token' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json'
```

I tried various combination but I still continue to get 401 error. What is wrong with my code and how should I fix it?

```
private apiUrl = 'https://api.collectapi.com/corona/countriesData';
  private token = 'your_token';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  getCoronaData(){
    const headers = new HttpHeaders ({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'authorization': `apikey ${this.token}`
    });

    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl, {headers});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first off you should know that error 401 means that you are not authorized to connect to the server you are trying to connect to. See [Mozilla http docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#client_error_responses) for more info.

So assuming you have a token, you should fill it in before sending it. It's also possible that you have already sent more requests than you are allowed to request. Collect API has different price tiers which you can check out [here](https://collectapi.com/api/corona/covid-19-coronavirus-statistics-api?tab=pricing).

Since your code is already returning 401 you likely connected to the correct URL. The only thing I can imagine is that you have a bad token or have gone over your allowed amount of calls.

Comment: well what I'm trying to achieve is not to fill api keys in code. They should be configurable

Comment: Well it needs to be filled in with a functioning code to get a return value from the API